# How to write in JQuery function which return new div?

Tags: jquery

How to write in JQuery function which return new div ? ( I get like parameter to function some object, base on that object and properties I need to return different color and text in div. Example: if I got F I paint red and write "fire", if I got W I paint blue and write "watter" ). Can anybody help

Answer (score 3):

```
function getADiv() {
    return $('<div/>', {
        text: 'hello',
        color: 'red'
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh interesting ! this syntax was created in which version of jQuery ?

Comment: @subtenante, since the dark ages , it's the [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm something like that ?

```
function makeDiv(type){
    var params;
    if(type == "F"){
        params = {text: "fire", color: "red"};
    }
    else if(type == "W"){
        params = {text: "water", color: "blue"};
    }
    else return null;

    return $("<div>")
        .text(params.text)
        .css("color", params.color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My take:

```
var newDiv = function(options){
    var html = '<div class="';

    if(options.color == 'R')
        html += 'rubyred';

    html += '">Element: ' + options.element + '</div>';
    return $(html);
};

var myNewDiv = newDiv({ color: 'R', element: 'fire' });
```

Or, simpler (not as fancy):

```
var newDiv = function(letter){
    var $d = $('<div>');

    if(letter == 'F')
        $d.html('fire').css('color', 'red');
    else if(letter == 'W')
        $d.html('water').css('color', 'blue');

    return $d;
};

var waterDiv = newDiv('W');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
function createDiv(type) {
    switch (type.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'f':
            return $('<div>').css({ color: 'red' }).text('Fire');
            break;

        case 'w':
            return $('<div>').css({ color: 'blue' }).text('Water');
            break;
    }
}
```

[**Live example** here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/GsEwg/1/)