# DataTable slidedown row.child()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I want to slide-down a div for each row when button is clicked. Currently dataTable row.child() calls format function in this form.

Refer fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/189Lp6u6/16/

```
function format ( d ) {
  return '<div class="slider">Test Message</div>';
}
```

Is it possible to return div for each row as like below

```
<div class="slider">Test Message</div>

function format(d){
  return $('div.slider');
}
```

Finally the jQuery looks like this.

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var row = table.row( tr );

  if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
    // This row is already open - close it
    row.child.hide();
    tr.removeClass('shown');
  } else {
    // Open this row
    row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
  }
});
```

Comment: please add fiddle, unclear what you are going to do

Comment: question is edited.

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309326/how-to-write-in-jquery-function-which-return-new-div

Comment: I don't want to write html inside the jquery function. I need to create separate div in html and call that div in jquery function

Comment: `I want to slide-down a div for each row when button is clicked.` - Your fiddle is already doing that? I'm not sure what you need exactly...?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `style="display: none"` for `.player` element and slide that one up/down when necessary.

For example:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row( tr );

    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
         row.child().find('.player').slideUp(400, function(){
            // This row is already open - close it            
            row.child.hide();

            tr.removeClass('shown');
         });
    }
    else {
        // Open this row
        row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
        row.child().find('.player').slideDown();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
} );
```

Also you can return jQuery element in `format()` function, `row.child()` accepts jQuery as an argument as well. See [`row.child()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child()) API method for more information.

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/189Lp6u6/336/) for code and demonstration.

See [Sliding child rows](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-02) post for alternative solution.

Comment: I mentioned that i don't want to write html part inside the jquery function.

Comment: I found a answer.  function format(d){
  return $('div.slider').html();
}

Answer (score 0):

To Avoid some extra transaction of Data from DB,by using this Code

```
$('#mytable').on('click', '.details-control', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);
    if (row.child() != null) {
        // This row is already open - close it
        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            row.child.show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } else {
        var childTable = format(id, date);
        row.child(childTable).show();
        tr.addClass('shown');
    }
});
```

Comment: Please use proper indentation.